# Pass boolean value to open a section from child to parent

Tags: vue.js

I have a child component. I click a button in the child component to open a section. The child component is called from parent component. I would like to show the section only after I click the showSection button.

Child Component

```
       <button
          @click="showSection()">
          Profile
        </button>
 
   data(){
      return{
        openPage:false,         
         }
       }
   
  methods: {
    showSection() {
    this.openPage=true;
    this.$emit('parent:showSection',this.openPage);
  },
 }
```

Parent Component

```
    <child v-if="openPage" @parent:showSection="openPage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you indicate, it is your child who owns the section to be displayed. So no need to create an event to warn the parent. I've created a very simple example that should help you a lot: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-open-sectioncomponent-by-clicking-on-button-4y1f5, where App.vue is the parent, HelloWorld.vue the child and superSction.vue the section that will be print by clicking on Profile Button in the child.